# How to apply zca on a huge image dataset with limited memory?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pca

what google told me is:

1. For `keras`, the `ImageDataGenerator` function seems to have a zca_whitening which can be used out of the box. But if this option been set, it requires to call the `ImageDataGenerator.fit` on the whole dataset X. So this is not an option.
2. For `sklearn`, the `IncrementalPCA` seems to work with a huge dataset, but I don't know how to rotate PCA to ZCA in an generator style.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem? If yes, please post here

Answer (score 1):

I have defined a function that might be helpful following the [ZCA transformation](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Implementing_PCA/Whitening):

```
def ZCAtransform(X,IPCA_model): 
      # get the Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues
      U = IPCA_model.components_.transpose()
      S = np.sqrt(IPCA_model.explained_variance_) 
      Xdemeand = (X-np.mean(X,0)).transpose()

      #get the transformed data 
      # Xproj' =  U * diag(1/(S+I*epsilon)) * U' * X_data 
      return (U.dot(np.diag(1/(S+IPCA_model.noise_variance_))).dot(U.transpose()).dot(Xdemeand)).transpose()

Xproj = ZCAtransform(X, ipca)
```

Following the given [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html) at Scikit-learn, I was able to generate the ZCA of Iris dataset as shown below:

[ZCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUFCK.png)  [Whitened PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwg97.png)

Comment: Can you please elaborate where IPCA_model comes from and give a full working example, including imported packages? Thanks